# Get sum of ObservableCollection column value

Tags: wpf

How to get sum of ObservableCollection column value to another property while changing data-grid column values, - wpf mvvm patern

Comment: Do you want to display as column in grid or summary in the bottom?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Summary in the bottom, I want to display sum of particular grid column values in bottom Text block, Here am using ObservableCollection data binding

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Mvvm.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding VM.MyList}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding VM.MyItem , Mode=TwoWay}"
                  />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding VM.Sum}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View Models:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> MyList { get; set; }

    ItemViewModel _myItem;
    public ItemViewModel MyItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _myItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _myItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyItem");
            OnPropertyChanged("Sum");
        }
    }

    public int Sum
    { 
        get
        {
            return MyList.Sum(a=>a.Amount);
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        MyList.Add(new ItemViewModel { Amount = 5});
        MyList.Add(new ItemViewModel { Amount = 6});
    }

}

public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        int _amount;
        public int Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return _amount;
            }
            set
            {
                _amount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Amount");
            }
        }
        //Other properties like Id, transactionDate, ...

    }
```

Main window code behind:

```
    public MainViewModel VM { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VM = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = this;

    }
```

Comment: So in this case, the Item ViewModel is a nested class inside the MainViewModel, which is convenient, because it allows you to fire the PropertyChanged event for Sum from within the MyItem setter. Is it possible in general to do this if the ViewModel for the item in the container isn't a nested class of the ViewModel that exposes the ObservableCollection?